# Easier way of getting the current loop number during for in loop?

Tags: objective-c, for-in-loop

I'm writing a `for in` loop to read a list of names from an NSArray, here is my code.

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Luke",@"James",@"Fred",@"Harry", nil];

for (NSString *name in names) {

    NSLog(@"%@",name);

}
```

What I am trying to determine is wether there is an easier way to get the current loop number without adding a variable outside the loop like so..

```
int number = 0;

for (NSString *name in names) {

    number++;
    NSLog(@"%i - %@",number,name);

}
```

Is there a built in 'loop number' property that can be accessed during a for loop? - Am I barking up the wrong tree? Should I just use the variable and get over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is reasonable (although I'd put `number++` at the end of the loop). Usually when I need a loop index, I avoid fast enumeration and use a more traditional for loop:

```
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {
    NSString *name = names[i];
    NSLog(@"%i - %@", i, name);
}
```

Comment: cheers, the for-in is real nice tho.. shame it's not like magic @tom

Comment: @Wezly Actually, Tom is not right. You can get the index of an object. See my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3, I see where you are coming from, although I was kinda hoping to get the index or loop number from the for loop instead of checking the array again.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the index, use a standard 3-part for loop, or the `number` counter with a while loop. No way to magically get the index in the `for...in` style loop.

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite a bit of a hack. You could either use a normal for loop instead of fast enumeration, or enumerate the objects using a block, or you can also use the `indexOfObject:` method inside the for loop (but this is really **discouraged** since it works only if you have only unique objects in the array, and anyways the repeated lookup makes it slower). All in all, try this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < names.count; i++) {
    NSString *name = [names objectAtIndex:i];
    // and "i" already stores the index
}
```

or this:

```
[names enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // use obj and idx
}];
```

and this is also possible, but don't do it:

```
for (NSString *name in names) {
    int idx = [names indexOfObject:name];
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: but don't do it.. because its slower than a simple `int++;` ?

Comment: @Wezly Pretty much, yes, but mainly because it is broken if you have the same object twice in the array :)

Comment: @H2CO3, yeah, that will (usually) work, but it's a really lame solution, because you end up searching the array for the current element on every pass through the loop. This has the potential to get *really* slow with a large array.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Yeah, basically you get `O(n ^ 2)` instead of `O(n)` - if `NSArray` works how we expect it to work. [Too bad it doesn't.](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html)